# Any evidence for the claim that Padma Purana was interpolated by the Jains?

Tags: history, padma-purana, interpolation, evidence

Many people say that Padma Purana was interpolated by the Jains.

Does any historian support this claim?
Is there any evidence in support of this claim?

Comment: Which people say this? where did you hear or read about this claim?

Comment: BTW the user who created the tag "evidence" must be awarded :P

Comment: What Madhavachraya followers told

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the padma purana of hinduism literature with the padma purana written by Ravisena in Jainism. There is also a padma purana written by Chandrakriti of Buddhism tradition.

The jainism text gives an [alternate ramayana](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=CU92nFk5fU4C&pg=PA339&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false), which is similar to the ramayana of the [jainism tradition written by Vimalasuri](https://www.livehistoryindia.com/story/snapshort-histories/jain-ramayana-a-non-violent-retelling/).